# How to manipulate filenames with whitespace using IFS in dash shell?

Tags: shell, dash-shell

I try to print and manipulate all filenames in current directory and there are some filenames containing whitespace. But when I use `IFS=$'\n’` to delimite filenames, it also remove character "n" from filenames.
Here is my code

```
#!/bin/dash
IFS=$'\n'
for file1 in $(ls)
do
    echo "$file1"
done
```

It should print

```
apple.txt
different.txt    #
empty.txt
hello  word.txt
ifstest.sh
one.txt          #
same.txt
```

But the result is

```
apple.txt
differe    #
t.txt      #
empty.txt
hello  word.txt
ifstest.sh
o          #
e.txt      #
same.txt
```

What should I do to avoid that?

Comment: Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Also `$'\n'` is not syntax dash understands.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you are using `ls` together with the loop.

If you don't need hidden files (i.e. those where the name starts with a `.` to be included), you can achieve your goal with

```
for file1 in *
do
  echo "$file1"
done
```

I assume that you want to do more processing with the file than just writing its name to stdout, because if you want to do the latter, you could do without a loop and simply write

```
ls -1
```

or (to include hidden files)

```
ls -1A
```

The `-1` ensures that the filenames are output at the start of the line. Without this option, `ls` would prepend each file name with a single space.